# 404 error in index.php/user but not is index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

404 page not found after creating .htaccess file. Already check config file , enable rewrite mode. Index file is showing blog/index.php is working but index.php/user is not. Already checked user.php.  this is code for user.php

(using codeigniter)

```php
<?PHP 
class User extends MY_Controller{
}

echo "user file in controller for public";
?>
```

---

### and this is output

> user file in controller for public
> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Save your controller as `User.php` with following code.

```
<?PHP
class User extends MY_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    echo "user file in controller for public";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set your default controller?
$route['default_controller']   = 'MY_Controller';

or do that

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter [change log](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html) says

> Changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be **Ucfirst**
>   and everything else in lowercase).

So you controllers and files name should be

- My_controller (only M upper case rest lower case)
- Public_controller
- Application_controller
- Foo_controller

> class User extends MY_Controller{ }

So Your file name must be `User.php`

> Ie: File name = Class name